# Как передать переменную php файлу во время выполнения по крону?

Tags: php, linux, cron

Друзья,
Есть файл `hello.php`
Нужно передать файлу переменную извне, то есть если бы сам файл находился в папке с вебсайтом, то выглядело бы это примерно так:

```
http://helloworld.com/hello.php?param=1
```

но в данном случае к файлу я обращаюсь не через браузер, а посредством CRON
то есть файл грубо говоря запускается так:

```
php hello.php?param=1
```

Сервер выдаёт ошибку:

```
Could not open input file: hello.php?param=1
```

Полагаю должен быть какой-то другой способ передать php файлу переменную `param`?

Comment: просто передавайте как параметры, и получайте как параметры
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: как вариант http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getopt.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Крон:

```
php hello.php foo
```

Содержимое:

```
print_r($argv[1]);
```

Проверка количества параметров

```
if($argc>1){//действие
}
```